# Squeryl join with null columns

Tags: sql, scala, join, playframework, squeryl

Let's say I have a table that contains ids that relate to other tables. I want to get all the objects because the combination of the tables makes up one object. Naturally I'd join them but I have an issue when some of the fields are optional. So I want to "get all" using this.

```
from(mainTable,
  optionalFieldTable,
  optionalFieldTable,
  requiredFieldTable1,
  requiredFieldTable2)((main,o1,o2,r1,r2) =>
  where(
    (main.someId1 === r1.id) and
    (main.someId2 === r2.id) and
    (main.optId1.inhibitWhen(main.optId1 == None) === o1.id) and
    (main.optId2.inhibitWhen(main.optId2 == None) === o2.id))
  select(main,o1,o2,r1,r2)
  ).toList
```

The above gives me an empty list. If I remove the optional fields from the query all together though it works. So what I'm wondering if there is a special way to test if the optional ids are None or Some other than the inhibit when?

I suspect that it has something to do with returning the tuple because it's trying to return to O1 and O2 object and not Option[O1] and Option[O2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd probably want to use the join syntax like:

```
join(mainTable, 
  requiredFieldTable1, 
  requiredFieldTable2, 
  optionalFieldTable1.leftOuter, 
  optionalFieldTable2.leftOuter)((main,r1,r2,o1,o2) => 
  select(main,o1,o2,r1,r2)
  on(main.someId1 === r1.id, 
     main.someId2 === r2.id,
     main.optId1 === o1.map(_.id),
     main.optId2 === o2.map(_.id)))
```

That query should work for you. In the above, it should just return `None` for `o1` and `o2` when the fields do not exist. By using the `outerJoin`, Squeryl takes care of the inhibit part for you. You can take a look at this for reference: http://www.squeryl.org/docs/0.9.5/joins.html

Comment: This is great, didn't realize the join syntax had this ability. Do you know how I would implement my orderBy function in this? `orderBy(main.category,main.name)` I typically had it after the select but doing that here renders no change.

Comment: `orderBy` should work in that situation. I've definitely used it before, but I can't remember if I ever tried it when returning a Tuple. I know it's not quite the same, but if that doesn't work, you could always use `sortWith` on the list that gets returned.

Comment: I was using sortWith but someone told me it's a fairly bad practice to do so because it doesn't take advantage of the dbs indexing. It seems when I use orderBy after the select it doesn't work because the on has not been applied yet. But it is not valid after the on.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is strictly bad practice as there are many times when sorting in the database is not possible or practical. However, when it makes sense - the performance will generally be better since it can make use of indexes and other optimizations plus it does not need to create additional objects subject to garbage collection. I am not sure why it is not working in this case, but if you want to see the underlying SQL you can call `.statement` on your query and it should return the String - perhaps that will yield a further clue.

Comment: Thanks your your input, it ended up being a pebkac error anyway. =]